# Can't connect to my websocket with real ip

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I have an php websocket (ratchet) which allways listen localhost on 8080 port and i can connect to them nicely without server on localhost by this js code: `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat")` or with server (apache) on my local ip (192.168.1.63) by this js code: `new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.63:8080/chat")`.

But if i use apache server and my real ip like 2.60.41.83 (js code: `new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.63:8080/chat")`) then i getting error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://2.60.41.83:8080/chat?encoding=text' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

connection refuse, but i pretty sure what 8080 port is open and listen my websocket connections.

If i delete ip port in this request, i getting 404(Not found) error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://2.60.41.83/chat?encoding=text' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

If i also delete "/chat" path i getting 302(Redirect) error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://2.60.41.83/?encoding=text' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

I getting all this errors no metter turn in my apache or not.

I try to modify my apache by open `proxy_module` and `proxy_wstunnel_module` and modify my virtualhost:

```
#NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@diskyp
    DocumentRoot "D:/XAMPP/htdocs/site"
    ServerName 2.60.41.83:80
    ErrorLog "logs/serv-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/serv-access.log" common
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8080/chat [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           http://127.0.0.1/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass /ws/ ws://localhost:8080/chat
    ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://localhost:8080/chat
</VirtualHost>
```

And also connect with "/ws/" path like `new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.63/ws")` but it still giving me 404 error.

So now i really stack here and need some help.

P.S. Sorry for my english, it's not my home language.

Comment: just a quick question: are you aware that 192.168.1.63 is a *private* IP address that's only accessible from your local network? there's not enough evidence to definitely say that this is the problem, but if i had to bet...?

Comment: yes, 192.168.1.63 is local address of my machine and 2.60.41.83 is my real ip

Comment: and now imagine, some arbitrary server out there in the internet (which, for all intents and purposes, yours is) - making an arbitrary connection to one of your local computers. do you think, from a security standpoint, that should be possible *at all*?

Comment: i think apache take care of this and he must redirect web request to local, but how does this things help me?